# Como editar dados de uma table em uma modal bootstrap?

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

Como carregar uma modal bootstrap através de um link dentro de uma tag `< td >` e enviar juntamente valor da coluna **Codigo**, **Nome** e **Data** exemplo:

**jquery:**

```
$(document).on("click", "#lnkEditar", function () {
        $('#cadModal').modal('show');
    });
```

**Modal**

```
<div id="cadModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Fechar">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Segmento - Editar</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="divEditarSegmento">
                @Html.Partial("_EditarSegmento", Model.Segmento)
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-close"></i> Fechar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnLimparCamposSegmento"><i class="fa"></i> Limpar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnGravarSegmento"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Gravar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

**Partial**

```
@model site.Entidade.Segmento
<form id="frmEditar">

                <div class="row">
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Codigo)
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.codigo)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.codigo, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-md-2">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nome)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Nome, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Data)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Data, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>

    </div>
```

**table html:**

```
<tbody>
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Segmentos.Count; i++)
            {
            <tr>
                <td><a href="#" id="lnkEditar" name="lnkEditar" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs btn-social-icon"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a></td>
                <td>@Model.Segmentos[i].Codigo</td>
        <td>@Model.Segmentos[i].Nome</td>
                <td">@Model.Segmentos[i].Data</td>
            </tr>
            }
    </tbody>
```

Comment: Inclua na pergunta também o partial `_EditarSegmento`

Comment: @Isac adicionei a Partial no post

Comment: O objetivo é mostrar os dados na modal quando é clicada ? Nas `textboxes` que vem da `partial` ?